# what should be the wattage or voltage of components

Tags: maximum-ratings

What should be the wattage and voltage of components used in a guitar pedal?
im using the following components

Transistor MPSA13

RESISTOR 10K 10KILOOHMS

FILM CAPACITOR 100nf code 104

Electrolytic capacitor 2.2uf

Diode 1n4148 or 1n914

Ill be connecting it to a 9v battery so what should be the voltage range of components?
resistor of 1/4 w

for eg a Electrolytic capacitor of 10uf has 250v so will that be compatible with 9v battery or the voltage should be <= 9v?

Comment: Where did you get your circuit diagram and parts list from?  That source should have specified the voltage and current capabilities.  If it didn't you probably should take the time to learn some basic electronics.  You don't want to either blow up components or yourself (granted a 9VDC circuit is unlikely to do the latter).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electronics

Comment: We need a schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question depends entirely upon the circuit in which the component will be used.  However, using a 9V battery as the only power source limits what damage you can do. :)

For instance, it's not unusual (and this is from old, old memory, so I could be wrong) for an overdrive or compression pedal to be capable of amplifying a signal times 100.  However, you'd wear a 9 volt battery out pretty fast if it was consistently used at that setting...

Answer (score 0):

As long as all your components are rated to higher than the voltage and current you will be using, you will be fine.

In your example, a 250v capacitor will easily handle whatever you throw at it from a 9v supply.

If you want specific guidance, and even comments on your circuit design, we have a flourishing [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you have a schematic along with your parts list there?  That will be important.

I recommend you visit the forums on Guitar PCB and read through their newbie section.  They have a crash course PDF that will help answer some of these questions:
http://www.guitarpcb.com/apps/forums/topics/show/7156859-crash-course-in-pedal-building-

A 250V capacitor is likely way too much for within a pedal.  It will be physically larger.  Anything over 12V should be fine, but I'd probably get 25V or 35V audio grade caps.  Resistors can all be 1/4 Watt as you've mentioned.

Mammoth electronics sells lots of parts for DIY pedal builders.

There is also a good step-by-step of someone building a pedal, along with his parts search recommendations:
http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Rat-Clone-Distortion-Guitar-Effect-Pedal---The/

Comment: Side note: "audio grade" capacitors are debatable as to whether they are better or not.  But those parts are so inexpensive you may as well...